# AWS GLUE Image certificate related issue

Tags: aws-glue-spark

I am new to Docker . Please help in resolving the issue.

I have created Docker compose file mentioned below :

```
version: "2"

services:
 spark:
  image: glue/spark:latest
  container_name: spark
**  build: ./spark**
  hostname: spark
  ports:
   - "8888:8888"
   - "4040:4040"
  entrypoint : sh 
  command : -c "/home/glue_user/jupyter/jupyter_start.sh"
  volumes:
  - ../app/territoryhub-replication:/home/glue_user/workspace/jupyter_workspace
```

Docker file which is getting called in build section is as follows :

```
FROM amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_3.0.0_image_01

USER root
RUN mkdir -p /root/.aws
RUN echo "[default]\nregion=us-east-1" >> /root/.aws/config
```

logs from Docker is as follows :

```
Starting Jupyter with SSL

/home/glue_user/jupyter/jupyter_start.sh: line 4: livy-server: command not found

[I 2022-05-12 15:41:33.032 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully linked.

[I 2022-05-12 15:41:33.044 ServerApp] nbclassic | extension was successfully linked.

[I 2022-05-12 15:41:33.046 ServerApp] Writing Jupyter server cookie secret to /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/jupyter_cookie_secret

[I 2022-05-12 15:41:33.541 ServerApp] sparkmagic | extension was found and enabled by notebook_shim. Consider moving the extension to Jupyter Server's extension paths.

[I 2022-05-12 15:41:33.541 ServerApp] sparkmagic | extension was successfully linked.

[I 2022-05-12 15:41:33.541 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully linked.

[W 2022-05-12 15:41:33.556 ServerApp] All authentication is disabled.  Anyone who can connect to this server will be able to run code.

[I 2022-05-12 15:41:33.558 ServerApp] notebook_shim | extension was successfully loaded.

[I 2022-05-12 15:41:33.560 LabApp] JupyterLab extension loaded from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyterlab

[I 2022-05-12 15:41:33.560 LabApp] JupyterLab application directory is /usr/local/share/jupyter/lab

[I 2022-05-12 15:41:33.565 ServerApp] jupyterlab | extension was successfully loaded.

[I 2022-05-12 15:41:33.569 ServerApp] nbclassic | extension was successfully loaded.

[I 2022-05-12 15:41:33.569 ServerApp] sparkmagic extension enabled!

[I 2022-05-12 15:41:33.569 ServerApp] sparkmagic | extension was successfully loaded.

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/bin/jupyter-lab", line 8, in <module>

    sys.exit(main())

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_server/extension/application.py", line 584, in launch_instance

    serverapp = cls.initialize_server(argv=args)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_server/extension/application.py", line 557, in initialize_server

    find_extensions=find_extensions,

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 88, in inner

    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_server/serverapp.py", line 2421, in initialize

    self.init_httpserver()

  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jupyter_server/serverapp.py", line 2251, in init_httpserver

    max_buffer_size=self.max_buffer_size,

  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/util.py", line 288, in __new__

    instance.initialize(*args, **init_kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/httpserver.py", line 191, in initialize

    read_chunk_size=chunk_size,

  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/tornado/tcpserver.py", line 134, in __init__

    'certfile "%s" does not exist' % self.ssl_options["certfile"]

ValueError: certfile "/home/glue_user/.certs/my_key_store.pem" does not exist
```

Getting
ValueError: certfile "/home/glue_user/.certs/my_key_store.pem" does not exist while  trying to create and run aws glue locally using docker .

Answer (score 1):

For now in order to make it work I have added environment variable :
DISABLE_SSL="true"

I am not sure if it is correct way of resolving it.